# URL redirections for normal users and bots

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using `UrlRewriteFilter` for URL redirections, What I intend to do is to deliver two different url redirections, one for normal users and one for google or facebook `Bots`

As an example I want to have something like below:

```
Normal user:  us.example.com/eng/article123.html

Bots:         example.com/us/eng/article123.html
```

What would be the right way to achieve this? Should I implement this manually? or there are better options to do this?
 Would be nice if the solution be independent of spring or any other complex frameworks. Thanks.

Comment: Which part are you asking about, how to detect the user-agent or how to redirect?

Comment: I ask about the redirection

Comment: It can't be done with a UrlRewriteFilter since those operate based on the url itself, not on the headers.